# How to include dynamically ruby file

Tags: ruby

I want to include all the ruby files in a directory that implement the function `toto()`.

In python I will do:

```
res = []
for f in glob.glob("*.py"):
  i = __import__(f)
  if "toto" in dir(i):
    res.append(i.toto)
```

and I could use the list like this:

```
for toto in res:
  toto()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby imports are very different than in Python - in Python files and modules are more or less the same thing, in Ruby they are not. You'll have to create your modules manually:

```
res = []
Dir.glob("*.rb") do |file|
  # Construct a class based on what is in the file,
  # and create an instance of it
  mod = Class.new do
    class_eval File.read file
  end.new

  # Check if it has the toto method
  if mod.respond_to? :toto
    res << mod
  end
end

# And call it
res.each do |mod|
  mod.toto
end
```

Or maybe more Ruby idiomatic:

```
res = Dir.glob("*.rb").map do |file|
  # Convert to an object based on the file
  Class.new do
    class_eval File.read file
  end.new
end.select do |mod|
  # Choose the ones that have a toto method
  mod.respond_to? :toto
end

# Later, call them:
res.each &:toto
```